# Integrating $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ in an unusual way.

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

We have
$$
\int \sqrt{1-x^2}\,\mathrm dx.
$$

The integral above can be easily done using trig-sub. But a question rose during class: "Can it be done without using trig sub?" And [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14L7AJs3b2HVeq0KNznOrZEdL1rXYpWTL/view?usp=sharing)'s the work. Even without using trig sub, I understand this way of work is not optimal. But I'm not looking for the best way to solve it. I'm looking for *why this answer is wrong*. At first, I suspected that it is the correct answer but just written in different form, probably by some trig identities. But when I graphed both correct result and this result, they look different. Furthermore, when I find the derivative, I don't get the given integral, so it's obviously wrong, but I'm having trouble finding what step is wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Below's the summary. For a side scratch work, I hope you can find it from the link as it's hard to show below, and I hope you understand.

From$$\int\sqrt{1-x^2}dx$$,
multiply both the numerator and the denominator by $\sqrt{1-x^2}$, and get
$$=\int\frac{1-x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$. Using integration by parts with choices $u=1-x^2$ and $dv=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$, it becomes
$$=(1-x^2)\sin^{-1}x+2\int x\sin^{-1}x\,dx$$Let $I_1=\int x\sin^{-1}x\,dx$ and rewrite it as
$$=(1-x^2)\sin^{-1}x+2I_1$$
For $I_1$, do another integration by parts with choices $u=\sin^{-1}x$ and $dv=x\,dx$.
$$I_1=\frac{1}{2}x^2\sin^{-1}x-\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx$$
Let $I_2=\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx$, and rewrite it as
$$I_1=\frac{1}{2}x^2\sin^{-1}x-\frac{1}{2}I_2$$
$$I_2=\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx=\int x\cdot\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx$$
Use substitution with $u=1-x^2$, which means $-\frac{1}{2}\,du=x\,dx$ and $x=\sqrt{1-u}$ if $x>0$ or $x=-\sqrt{1-u}$ if $x<0$.
If $x>0$, then
$$I_2=-\frac{1}{2}\int\sqrt{1-u}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}\,du$$
For the integral, use integration by parts with choices $a=\frac{\sqrt{1-u}}{\sqrt{u}}$ and $dv=du$. Then,
$$=-\frac{1}{2}\bigg(u\sqrt{\frac{1-u}{u}}+\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{u}{u^{3/2}\sqrt{1-u}}\,du\bigg)$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2}u\sqrt{\frac{1-u}{u}}-\frac{1}{4}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}\sqrt{1-u}}\,du$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{u}\sqrt{1-u}-\frac{1}{4}\cdot I_3$$,
where $I_3=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}\sqrt{1-u}}\,du$.
Similarly, if $x<0$,
$$I_2=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{u}\sqrt{1-u}+\frac{1}{4}\cdot I_3$$
For $I_3$, use substitution with choice $z=\sqrt{u}$. Then
$$I_3=2\sin^{-1}\sqrt{u}+C$$
Substitute $I_3$ into $I_2$, and get
$$I2=
 \begin{cases} 
      -\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{u}\sqrt{1-u}-\frac{1}{2}\sin^{-1}\sqrt{u}+C, & x>0 \\
      \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{u}\sqrt{1-u}+\frac{1}{2}\sin^{-1}\sqrt{u}+C, & x<0
   \end{cases}
$$
$$=
 \begin{cases} 
      -\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{x^2}-\frac{1}{2}\sin^{-1}\sqrt{1-x^2}+C, & x>0 \\
      \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{x^2}+\frac{1}{2}\sin^{-1}\sqrt{1-x^2}+C, & x<0
   \end{cases}
$$
But $\sqrt{x^2}=x$ if $x>0$, and $-x$ if $x<0$. Thus,
$$=
 \begin{cases} 
      -\frac{1}{2}x\sqrt{1-x^2}-\frac{1}{2}\sin^{-1}\sqrt{1-x^2}+C, & x>0 \\
      -\frac{1}{2}x\sqrt{1-x^2}+\frac{1}{2}\sin^{-1}\sqrt{1-x^2}+C, & x<0
   \end{cases}
$$
Substitute this into $I_1$ and get
$$I_1=
 \begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{2}x^2\sin^{-1}x+\frac{1}{4}x\sqrt{1-x^2}+\frac{1}{4}\sin^{-1}\sqrt{1-x^2}+C, & x>0 \\
      \frac{1}{2}x^2\sin^{-1}x+\frac{1}{4}x\sqrt{1-x^2}-\frac{1}{4}\sin^{-1}\sqrt{1-x^2}+C, & x<0
   \end{cases}
$$
Substitute this and combine like terms and finally get
$$\int\sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx=
 \begin{cases} 
      \sin^{-1}x+\frac{1}{2}x\sqrt{1-x^2}+\frac{1}{2}\sin^{-1}\sqrt{1-x^2}+C, & x>0 \\
      \sin^{-1}x+\frac{1}{2}x\sqrt{1-x^2}-\frac{1}{2}\sin^{-1}\sqrt{1-x^2}+C, & x<0
   \end{cases}
$$

Comment: +1 for "dank integral.pdf"

Comment: For those who cannot access the pdf, I could access, maybe try to type out the work in the question.

Comment: You'll need trig at some point. And it could be done without any substitution, just geometrically, because the graph of $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is the upper semicircle of the unit circle centered at $0$. So, it's a sum or difference, depending on the sign of $x$, of areas of a sector and a triangle.

Comment: Also note that $\operatorname{sgn}(x)\sin^{-1}x + \sin^{-1}\sqrt{1-x^2}=\pi/2$.

Comment: Please write a summary of your computations in the question using mathjax (so with less equations and with more words, so we can understand what you do, and actually it might help you to find the answer ...) Right now it is quite painful to read.

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein Thank you for the input. But as I stated, I'm trying to find which part went mathematically incorrect, not another way to solve the integral.

Comment: I edited. I tried to include all the work neatly as much as possible. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result is wrong as stated and the reason is the substitution $u=1-x^2$ which requires you to “divide into cases”.

You do essentially like
$$
\int e^{|x|}\,dx=\begin{cases} e^{x}+c & x>0 \\[6px] -e^{-x}+c & x<0 \end{cases}
$$
which is wrong unless you make it right:
$$
\int e^{|x|}\,dx=c+\begin{cases} e^{x}+a & x\ge0 \\[6px] -e^{-x}+b & x\le0 \end{cases}
$$
where $a,b$ are to be determined so the function defined by cases is continuous, so $e^0+a=-e^{-0}+b$ and you can choose $a=-1,b=1$ to make things symmetric.

Look at the [graphs on Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9jrvtfvfyn):

[image]

So it isn't “completely wrong”, but you need to connect the two branches like in the $e^{|x|}$ example.

The initial idea is good, but then you overcomplicate it:
$$
I=\int\sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx
=\int\biggl(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}+x\frac{-x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\biggr)\,dx
=\arcsin x+J
$$
where $J$ is the integral of the second summand, which can be done by parts:
$$
J=\int x\frac{-x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx
=x\sqrt{1-x^2}-\int\sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx
=x\sqrt{1-x^2}-I
$$
Thus we have
$$
I=\arcsin x+x\sqrt{1-x^2}-I
$$
and finally
$$
I=\frac{1}{2}(\arcsin x+x\sqrt{1-x^2})+c
$$

Comment: yes i know the result is wrong and know this is not the most elegant way, but as i stated, i'm looking for what went wrong, not another way to solve it

Comment: @HarryHong I added the explanation

Comment: ah I just realized I only graphed it wrong in Desmos and that's why i thought the answer was wrong. you're right. after adjusting the constant of the integration, to make the function continuous and differentiable the answer is correct, although I think (please enlighten me if I'm wrong) it's not necessary and the result is still considered completely correct. This was not of my work btw, but it was started by one of my students who didn't learn trig sub and I just wanted to help him finish this. Thank you very much

Comment: As a side note, your the original integrals are correct if you take the real part for $-1<x<1$. See the plot [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+re%28arcsin%28x%29%2B1%2F2x+sqrt%281-x%5E2%29-1%2F2x+arcsin%28sqrt%281-x%5E2%29%29%29)

Comment: @TymaGaidash I beg to disagree about “correctness”. As written, the solution isn't even continuous.

Comment: @egreg I see. I agree. Thank you!